# How to show someone  who you previously marked for Facebook to hide from yours news feed

Tags: facebook, news-feed

I previously marked someone for Facebook to hide from my news feed - how can I undo that process and see their updates in my news feed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Go to your news feed and hit the <kbd>End</kbd> key to navigate straight to the bottom of the page.
- click the `Edit Options` links on the right hand side
- a pop up will be displayed with a section called **Hide posts from:** then a sub section called **Friends**.
- Click the `x` next to the friends name who you no longer want to hide.
- Click `Save`